# My rails project has two different I18n.load_path and I18n.locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale

So I'm translating my project to handle different languages. I already translated almost all my code from folder /app/views/ and /lib/modules/. Didn't have any problems with these.

Thing is now i want to translate a file that is telling me that "I18n.locale" is different from the one i have, and the load_path is also wrong.

So I18n is working good with the files i mentioned before, is already translating to Spanish. but when i get to this file, it tells me that the locale is :en (the default one) and the load_path is wrong, is only looking for locales in some gems like paperclip (i guess is the default load_path).

I'm very confused. Why this file wasn't affected by the variables set from the application.rb? Why I have two different I18n.locale in my project? How can I solve this?

I already solved the load_path problem by loading again the path in this file like in application.rb, but with the I18n.locale is different, since I have to take the :preferred_locale of the user in the database to assign it, but apparently I can't do that since User.all gives me error, I can't retrieve the users from my database, but I can do other queries.

What is happening? Thanks in advance.

edit: btw this is my first question so go easy on me :)

edit2: the file is not a class nor a module, its just doing a require from other module and setting some variables. The file is in lib/file_with_problem.rb

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone encounters this problem, where in certain files they dont have the correct load_path from I18n, i solved by using the global variable for I18n in the application.rb So, if i had this:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/modules/#{module_name}/config/locales/*.yml"]
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

I solve by adding the same lines, but without the config, and with the first letter in caps.

```
I18n.load_path += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/modules/#{module_name}/config/locales/*.yml"]
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem quite recently after updating my rails. The solution that works for me is to use the `locale.rb` in the `config/initializers` folder and use the method from the I18n class directly:

```
# Where the I18n library should search for translation files
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

# Permitted locales available for the application
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :"sv-se", :"en-se"]
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.